# Robolectric KeyStoreKeyGenerator

Tags: java, android, kotlin, robolectric

I'm using in my project Dagger2, KeyStoreKeyGenerator (from in.co.ophio.secure) and I want to use Robolectric to test my Fragment.

I inject presenter to my Fragment. Presenter has userPrefs injected. UserPrefs have KeyStoreKeyGenerator implemented

```
class UserPreferences(val application: App) : UserPreferencesAPI {
// another methods and fields
    private val keyGenerator = KeyStoreKeyGenerator.get(application, application.packageName)
}
```

this is my presenter

```
 class MainPresenter(...,
                        val sharedPreference: UserPreferencesAPI)
```

and this is my test

```
private MainFragment fragment;
private MainActivity activity;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
    fragment = MainFragment.Companion.newInstance();
}

@Test
public void shouldBeNotNull() {
    Assertions.assertThat(activity).isNotNull();
}
```

After running test I see:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.security.KeyStore.isHardwareBacked(KeyStore.java:318)
    at android.security.KeyChain.isBoundKeyAlgorithm(KeyChain.java:397)
    at in.co.ophio.secure.core.KeyStoreKeyGenerator.<init>(KeyStoreKeyGenerator.java:41)
    at in.co.ophio.secure.core.KeyStoreKeyGenerator.get(KeyStoreKeyGenerator.java:56)
    at unofficial.coderoid.wykop.newapp.utils.UserPreferences.<init>(UserPreferences.kt:24)
```

Should I create shadow KeyStoreKeyGenerator? Should I wrap KeyStore class using interface?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve it by writing a custom shadow http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/

```
@Implements(android.security.KeyChain.class)
public class KeyChainShadow {
   @RealObject
   private KeyChain keyChain;


    @Implementation
    public static boolean isBoundKeyAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

don't forget to annotate your test with

```
@Config(shadows = KeyChainShadow.class)
```